# Meteor .versions file update

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

I am developing a small meteor package, and I know that, to be consistent with the builds, meteor will create a .versions file in my package when I publish it.

That's fine, and I understand that, but, as the .versions should go in my version control (git) and I would like to commit the release before publishing it, is there a way to update the .versions package before publishing?

Also, the .versions file has a reference to the package itself. Is this necessary? If I'm developing version x.y.z of a package, why do I need to update both the package.js and the .versions file to reflect x.y.z?

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: why do you think you should change versions file? `versionsFrom` come from `package.json`

Comment: When creating a new version of the package, the .versions gets changed as it updates the package itself (which is my second question. why does it need it?)

Comment: Also, I can not commit my first release to git before publishing, as I will not have a .versions file

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a need to add it to version control b/c I don't think the set of calculated versions means anything in a stand-alone package outside of the context of a meteor project. I'm not really sure what the file is used for at all since it doesn't show up in `.meteor/packages` when you install the package. It might just be nothing more than a by-product of running the solver.

So I never check `.versions` into version control and I haven't encountered any problems.